# Windows phone 8 Enterprise distribution

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way to sideload a Windows phone 8 Enterprise app?
I can only find sideloading documentation on Windows 8 desktop store apps.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I have gone through that documentation. It says to create a Company hub app to distribute the app. What should I do if I do want to develop a Company hub application? Can I just keep the application on a server and allow the users to download it?

Comment: No, it's a lot more complicated than that. But to be honest, I have never used that, so I can't really answer any precise question. That's why I just commented on the question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sideloading is only a feature that is given to Company distributed applications. The company manages a MDM(Mobile Device Management) , and the APPX file is distributed through email or server or local storage.
The company has to have a Microsoft System Center 2012 for managing the applications . The phones are company specific and the apps can be directly deployed without going throgh the App store